# Hover on <li> haven't good size

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm using bootstrap and I have this code :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu-brands" style="width:210px;">
    {foreach $arr as $id => $r}
       <li><a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size:15px;font-family: PT Sans Narrow,PTSansNarrow;" href="#">{$r}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

I have this css:

```
.scrollable-menu-brands {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scrollable-menu-brands::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.scrollable-menu-brands::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.scrollable-menu-brands li a {
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
    background-color: red;
;}
```

But when hover an element of the list, background color is only for top of my element..
Look this screen:
[image: screen]

Someone understand please?
I don't understand why height of over is small like this...
If I increase height, it doesn't work.

Comment: is it possible to get a link or something to troubleshoot?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] - at first glance, though, it looks like you should add your hover to the `li` instead of the `a` - like `.dropdown-menu>li:hover{
  background-color: red;  
}`

Comment: add `display: block` to `a`

Comment: @MathAng make sure to flag my answer as usefull if this does it for you ;). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MathAng,

It looks like the height of your **A** and **LI** aren't matching the same height, the default height of the **LI** tag is 26 pixels in height. But at your CSS you're saying that it must be 10 pixels for the **A** tag.

What I prefer is or use:

```
.scrollable-menu-brands li a {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

instead of:

```
.scrollable-menu-brands li a {
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Or add height: 10px; to your **LI** tag, like so:

```
.scrollable-menu-brands li {
    height: 10px;
}
```

Hopefully this does the trick for you!